# Unity Camera Screenshot on mobile full of noise

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot using another camera in Unity. I have read some sample project and [watched this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-56p770t0U)

And now, I can take screenshot and save it somewhere when using Unity Editor. But when I build it into my Android devices, the images become full of noise.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
void Awake()
{
    myCamera = GetComponent<Camera>();  // Camera is disable in the scene
    myCamera.targetTexture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 24);
}

public void takeScreenShot(){
    myCamera.enabled = true;
    StartCoroutine(Capture());
}

IEnumerator Capture(){
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D result = new Texture2D(myCamera.targetTexture.width, myCamera.targetTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    myCamera.Render();
    RenderTexture.active = myCamera.targetTexture;

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, myCamera.targetTexture.width, myCamera.targetTexture.height);
    result.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);

    byte[] byteArray = result.EncodeToPNG();
    string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ScreenShot.png";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, byteArray);

    Debug.Log("ScreenShot saved to: " + filePath);

    Destroy(result);
    myCamera.enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out what's wrong here. The "Clear Flags" of my camera was set to be "Don't Clear". Changing the Clear Flags into "Depth only" fixes the problem.